# Prerender.io using Node js Middleware Version 2.2.2 getting HTTP 504 when attach url parameter _escaped_fragment

Tags: prerender

I have an issue with prerender.io Service and the node js middleware. My Server uses the https protocol. When I https://myserverurl/test?_escaped_fragment_=

than I get HTTP 504

Comment: Please send an email to support@prerender.io with some more information and we'd be happy to help!